# Repeat sequences where the start increases

Tags: r

So what I just did is this:

```
s1 <- seq(1, 3, by = 0.5)

rep(s1, 3)
# [1] 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0

s2 <- seq(-4, 4, by = 2)

rep(s2, each = 3)
# [1] -4 -4 -4 -2 -2 -2  0  0  0  2  2  2  4  4  4
```

Now I should code something that in the end should look like this:

> ```
> 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
> ```

1 to 5 5 times but the 1st number should always increase by 1.
How can I do that?

Comment: `rep(1:5, 5) + rep(0:4, each = 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mapply` :

```
inds <- 1:5
c(mapply(seq, inds, inds + 4))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to a corresponding matrix the `col`s.

```
m <- matrix(0:4, 5, 5) 
as.vector(m + col(m))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try `embed` like below

```
> n <- 5
> c(embed(seq(n + 4), n)[, n:1])
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rep`

```
n <- 5
seq_len(n) + rep(0:4, each = n)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```